# Count Rows in Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am very new in LINQ

I have written following query :

```
var duplicate =
    from  loginId in DataWorkspace.v2oneboxData.me_employees
    where loginId.me_login_name == this.me_login_name
              && loginId.me_pkey != this.me_pkey
    select loginId;
```

I want to count the rows returned in the result duplicate

I searched many of articles that says use duplicate.Count().  but i dont see count() in my intelisense

how do i count from result

Comment: I think the biggest trip up is missing using System.Linq but I bear in mind this also - [In LINQ, Don’t Use Count() When You Mean Any()](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/04/21/38598/)

Comment: @Coops link broke - new link below. In short Any() can be more efficient at the DB end: https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/in-linq-dont-use-count-when-you-mean-any-38598

Answer (score 26, accepted):

How about doing it using extension methods:

```
 var count = me_employees.Where(me => me.me_login_name == this.me_login_name && me.me_pkey != this.me_pkey).Count();
```

Even better:

```
var count = me_employees.Count(me => me.me_login_name == this.me_login_name && me.me_pkey != this.me_pkey);
```

BIG NOTE: Ensure that you have referenced System.Core. System.Data.Linq as well but I assume you already referenced it.

Comment: Still i dont find Count() method in Intellisese

Comment: Ensure you have added a reference to System.Core;

Comment: I got following error while adding System.Core assembly : " You can not add a reference to System.Core.dll as it was not built against the silverlight Runtime. Silverlight project will only work with Silverlight Assemblies.

Comment: In that case, make sure you are creating a You should create SilverLight Application project since they use their own versions of (lighter) assemblies. In other words, it wont work for an ASP.NET, WPF, or Console

Comment: If you go to the Add References dialog and two System.Core.dll are listed, one of them should work with Silverlight - you can use trial and error to determine which.

Comment: Thanks for you favorable replies: i solved the problem using : duplicate.Cast<me_emplyee>().count();

Answer (score 9):

You need the following line at the top of your file:

```
using System.Linq;
```

But there should be a little helper icon that appears over the missing reference on `Count` that has Visual Studio add this line automatically.

**Update**:
This is a complete compilable example:

```
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication11    {
    class Program
    {
        string me_login_name;
        int me_pkey;

        public static void Main()
        {
            new Program().Run();
        }

        private void Run()
        {
            IQueryable<v2oneboxDataEntity> me_employees = null;

            var duplicate =
                from  loginId in me_employees
                where loginId.me_login_name == this.me_login_name
                        && loginId.me_pkey != this.me_pkey
                select loginId;

            var count = duplicate.Count();            
        }

        // Define other methods and classes here
        class v2oneboxDataEntity 
        {
            public string me_login_name { get; set; }
            public int me_pkey { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

What version of Visual Studio are you using?  And what is your target version of the .NET framework?  (Requires >= VS 2008, and >= .NET 3.5.)

Comment: Actually i am using visual studio 2011 with .Net Framework 4.0 and the application is on Lightswitch So the v2oneboxDataEntity is a Database and  me_employees is a Datatable and it is auto generated. i can not create them seperatelly

Comment: sorry it is visual studio 2010 (typing mistak)

Comment: When you right click on `me_employees` in your code and choose "Go to definition", what does that line read?

Comment: public global::Microsoft.LightSwitch.Framework.EntitySet<global::LightSwitchApplication.me_employee> me_employees
        {
            get
            {
                return global::LightSwitchApplication.v2oneboxData.DetailsClass.GetValue(this, global::LightSwitchApplication.v2oneboxData.DetailsClass.PropertySetProperties.me_employees);
            }
        }

Comment: I'm having trouble finding any MSDN documentation on `Microsoft.LightSwitch.Framework.EntitySet`.  Is there by chance a `.AsQueryable` in the intellisense?

Comment: Ok, great.  So just do `.AsQueryable().Count()` and you should be set.

Comment: You mean to do duplication.AsQueryable().Count() ? then i dont find Count() method in duplication.AsQueryable() also :(

Comment: @ghanshyam.mirani Check if your project references `System.Core`

Comment: I got following error while adding System.Core assembly : " You can not add a reference to System.Core.dll as it was not built against the silverlight Runtime. Silverlight project will only work with Silverlight Assemblies.

Comment: @ghanshyam.mirani: You're going to have to start from the beginning again.  The queries are fine but apparently you don't have your projects set up correctly.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using lambda expressions then make sure you have referenced `System.Linq.Expressions` namespace.

```
var cardCount = datatable
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Where(p => p.Field<decimal>("SpotID") ==
        Convert.ToDecimal(currentActivatedSpot))
    .Count();
```

Comment: @Sandor : Thank you for bringing it to my notice. I'll keep these things in mind.